# Comparing an [NSURL path] to an NSString doesn't work

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I have this code:

```
NSLog([url path]);
if([url path] == @"/connect/login_success.html") {
    NSLog("IT WORKZ");
}
```

When I run my application, do the login etc... my console says:

```
2010-05-04 23:49:57.297 Framebook Test Application[8069:a0f] /connect/login_success.html
```

But it should also print `IT WORKZ` to the console, which it does not.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To compare strings, you use `isEqualToString:`. `==` tests pointer equality.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if([[url path] isEqualToString:@"/connect/login_success.html"]) {
    NSLog("IT WORKZ");
}
```

Comment: Mmm... I think you forgot a `:`